# I need buttons that adds a week to date and one to decrease

Tags: php, date, button, calendar, addition

This code shows the week number

```
<?php 
    $week_number = date("W");
    echo "Week " . $week_number; 
?>
```

and this code shows the dates in that week

```
<?php
$week_number = date("W");
$year = date("Y");
for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++){
    echo "<td>";
    echo date('d M', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$day))."\n";
    echo "</td>";
}
```

Its for a week view calender and what i need is a next and prev button to skip to next week and go back to prev week.. PLease help i cant find a solution to add one week or decrease on week with buttons.

Answer (score 1):

```
$last_week = (new DateTime('last week'))->format('d M');
$next_week = (new DateTime('next week'))->format('d M');
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/183665)

If you want to start from a different date the code wouldn't look much different:

```
$date      = $_GET['date']; // Sample value: 2014-08-19
$last_week = (new DateTime($date)->modify('last week'))->format('d M');
$next_week = (new DateTime($date)->modify('next week'))->format('d M');
```

Comment: how to make that into a button ?

Comment: Just use the `<button>` HTML tag. Now if you want to know how to make things happen when you press that button then your question is too broad...

Comment: the button is the thing i need, it needs to add or decrease the $week_number by one so the for loop gets it too

Comment: Just pass a date to the page with this code and pass the date as a a parameter to DateTime(). This will still work that way.

Comment: can you show me how thats done please ?  I dont nderstand how the button part works in code.

Comment: i realy need the button that calls the action part